# Long wait after flashing

Tags: rom-flashing, rom

I have a stock image for my tablet, and I am using DragonFace to edit it and PhoenixSuite to flash it.

The stock image flashes fine, and after the flash it immediately reboots (I don't have to do anything).

I can make changes to it via DragonFace and save it as a new img file.  After flashing the new file, sometimes it won't boot at all, sometimes it takes 5 min before it will boot.  I try many button combinations to trigger a boot.

Obviously, it could be a bad img (if I changed something critical) some of the time, but that isn't the case most of the time.  I know this because after a bit of waiting, the device does boot.  If after a few minutes there is no activity, I sometimes reflash the exact same image, and it boots (eventually).

My main question is how to shorten the long delay between flashing and booting.  It is making diagnosing my new image difficult.

Note, I disabled device encryption, and I know that works because the image flashes just fine with that modification (again, after a short wait).

Comment: In general, after flashing any Android OS, the first boot takes too long because how Android works. I think it takes too long because is "optimizing" all the apps (compiling to be run on ART) or something like this, and configuring stuffs. And it depends also on your hardware. AllWinner/RockChip CPUs are not powerful though.

Comment: I would think that, but there is no screen activity and adb can't find the device.  Also, when I flash the stock image, it boots immediately.  After flashing a new image, it is for all appearances dead.  Buttons do nothing.  Then magically after a few minutes (sometimes) it boots up.

Comment: So this depends on how you modifying your image

Comment: Agreed, I am using DragonFace.  If I open the stock image, make no changes, and then just save it as a new name and flash it, it does this.

Comment: I was about to point Dragon Face. I think the way the stock image is packed is different than the one Dragon Face does

Comment: That does appear to be the case.  If you are aware of any other such utility, please let me know!

Comment: Unfortunately I don't know any other ROM tools/utility or editor for AllWinner devices

Comment: Look into the simg2img tool.

Comment: Yeah, looks like my best bet is to switch to linux and use command line tools rather than windows tools.  Thank you for the help!